# Haskell: pattern matching on undefined values

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

As I understand it, Haskell's `undefined` value - of a particular type - is a value that can't be determined, for whatever reason (maybe there is no sensible definition, or the calculation diverges).  For instance: `undefined :: [Int]` is a list, so it must be constructed with either [] or (:), but it doesn't know which one!  Hence it makes sense that case splitting on undefined makes the whole expression undefined: I don't know whether `null (undefined :: [a])` is True or False, because I don't know whether `undefined :: [a]` is empty or not.

(By the way - if you disagree with my suggestion that `undefined` *is* built with a constructor, then surely `null (undefined :: [a])` should evaluate to False?  After all `undefined` isn't equivalent to []!)

However, Haskell pattern matching doesn't follow this way of thinking.

```
data Foo = Foo Int String  -- Only one data constructor

silly :: Foo -> Bool
silly (Foo _ _) = True

ghci> silly (undefined :: Foo)
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined    -- But whatever the value is, it must 
                                    -- be constructed with Foo.
                                    -- So why fail to match?
```

(I know that newtype behaves differently here.)

Also:

```
foo :: Int -> String -> Bool
foo 8 "Hello" = True
foo _ _       = False

ghci> foo undefined undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined     -- GOOD - can't tell which case to choose.

ghci> foo undefined "Hello"
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined     -- GOOD - still can't tell.

ghci> foo undefined "Goodbye"
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined     -- BAD  - should return false!
                                     -- Pattern match on first line should fail,
                                     -- because whatever the int is, the
                                     -- string can't match the given pattern.
```

I think the rules on pattern matching currently say that if a sub-pattern fails then the pattern should immediately fail; if it diverges, then the whole pattern should also diverge; and if it succeeds, then the next sub-pattern should be tried.  If all sub-patterns succeed, then the whole pattern succeeds.

What I am suggesting is that if any of the sub-patterns fail then the whole pattern should fail; if none fail but some diverge then the whole pattern should diverge; and if all succeed then the whole pattern should succeed.

Why is this not how Haskell does things?

---

EDIT:

So to summarise my interpretation of the responses I've read:

`undefined` should be read as "This would cause your program to run forever" not "This is not well defined", and `Exception: Prelude.undefined` should be read as "Watch out! Your program would have never terminated if undefined was an infinite loop" rather than "I don't know what to do because I don't know what value undefined is".

Could somebody please verify that this is correct?  If so then I will probably accept mb14's answer.

Thanks everyone. Sorry for being so slow on the uptake!

Comment: Is this actually a question, or only a suggestion? Also, any kind of pattern matching that tries to evaluate a diverging term to WHNF will show that behaviour. If you pattern match subpatterns, how do you know WHICH of the values will match, and which will diverge? Unfortunately, [you don't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and Haskell [isn't total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming). By the way, you might be interested in this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/pattern-matching/gadtpm.pdf.

Comment: It's a question - I'm sure there's a very good reason for the current rules, I just can't imagine what it is.

Comment: And sorry, you're going to have to go through the thing about the Halting problem more slowly.  Can't Haskell already decide whether something fails or diverges?

Comment: Oh, I see.  So matching the value x :: Int defined by x = x on the pattern 3 will never terminate and hence will cause a super-pattern to diverge as well.  But what about undefined, which the compiler can tell does diverge?

Comment: IIRC, `undefined = error "Prelude.undefined"`, and `error` is basically raising an exception: `error s = throw (errorCallException s)`. So it's an exception, hidden in the darks, getting thrown when you try to look into the value. And when you use `foo undefined "Goodbye"`, you're actually using `foo (undefined :: Int) "Goodbye"`, so the compiler still generates code that checks the value of `undefined`.

Comment: There's not much "magic" going on there, although a compiler could probably recognize the `undefined`. However, [sec 3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-230003.1) states that the program __must__ terminate if it encounters `_|_`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: Why though?  There's no problem with a never terminating calculation if it the result is irrelevant anyway, as above.

Comment: @Zeta, many programs fail to terminate when they encounter `_|_`! Ideally, they shouldn't terminate with wrong answers in that case, but compiler writers are likely to see that as a suggestion.

Comment: @dfeuer, yeah, bad phrasing on my side, sorry. *"The actual program behavior when an error occurs is up to the implementation"* However, after some sleep, I think my previous comment is completely off: if a program encounters `_|_`, how does it know it actually encountered `_|_` (apart from `undefined`, `error`, `<<loop>>` and some other checkable bottoms)? Either way, I think Rein's answer ties all the other answers together in a single post (although I'm considering to write an ELI5 style answer later).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you are saying that `undefined :: Foo` and `Foo undefined undefined` should be the same because (as you said `But whatever the value is, it must be constructed with Foo.)`.

This assumption is not correct. Foo *must* be constructed with `Foo` only if it *can* be constructed. What if I have `foo = if x then (Foo 1 "a")  else (Foo 2 "b")`. If `x` is undefined then trying to evaluate `f` diverges. At that point, there is no notion of constructor or not. It just diverges.

It is the same with your example `null (undefined :: [a])` should be `undefined` (diverge) as well because you need to try to evaluate the parameter of `null` to know if it's a `[]` or a `:`.

Undefined in Haskell is not magic, it's just a loop. You could define your own `loop = let x = x in x`. This will loop each time you try to evaluate it.
calling `null loop` or `sill loop` will loop and therefore is equal to `loop`, isn't it ?. Do you still consider that `loop :: Foo` and `Foo loop loop` are the same ? I don't. I expect `silly loop` to loop but not `silly (Foo loop loop)`.

The only difference between this `loop` and `undefined` is just that ghc can detect `undefined` is a loop and so break the look and display an error message instead of looping forever. It's just there for convenience and if it wasn't there, people would define `undefined = loop`.

Comment: *"I expect `silly loop` to loop but not `silly (Foo loop loop)`."* I really need to write this down.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I know that `null undefined` is `undefined` not `False`. So essentially, read `undefined` as "This would cause your program to run forever" not "This is not well defined", and read `Exception: Prelude.undefined` as "Watch out! Your program would have never terminated if undefined was loop" rather than "I don't know what to do because I don't know what value undefined is".  Perhaps undefined should really be called loop, or even neverTerminates?

Comment: Is that right?  If it is then I'll accept this answer and be very satisfied.

Comment: `undefined` is definetly not `I don't know what value it is`, there is `Nothing` for that. `undefined`means `it diverges` which is you can't expect GHC to reduce  `undefined :: Foo` to `Foo undefined undefined` or even pattern match on `undefined`. You can see more [there](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom).

Comment: @RhubarbAndC That's a possible reasonable interpretation of `undefined`. Another could be "this should never have happened! abort the program" or even "this was not implemented -- aborting".

Comment: @chi But... why is something not being implemented a problem *if the answer is irrelevant anyway.*  Surely, the only reason why lack of implementation is important is if the compiler can not determine how the program should proceed.

Comment: @mb14 I think Nothing is "not a value" in a completely different sense.  I am convinced on the diverging calculation front: if undefined represents and infinite loop, then the current rules make perfect sense.  However, I thought it could also mean "this person did not give a definition for this value" - so I don't know what it is.  In this case the current rules seem strange in the cases I showed above.  I'm beginning to suspect that this is not what undefined means at all - it's just a bad choice of name.  Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: "I don't know what it is" means "the compiler doesn't know what it is" above.

Comment: @RhubardAndC Loop on this own is not really usefull and its own. People don't really need to insert looping value in their code, unless when they need *A* value that need to implement later (which is the use case of *undefined*) Loop is only value which can fit this role.

Comment: @RhubarbAndC Indeed, it works as you describe. If the answer is irrelevant, you will never try to evaluate `undefined`, so no error occurs. If one instead does evaluate it, then that means the result is relevant, and unexpectedly so -- hence the runtime error.

Answer (score 5):

> (By the way - if you disagree with my suggestion that undefined is built with a constructor, then surely null (undefined :: [a]) should evaluate to False? After all undefined isn't equivalent to []!)

This means it shouldn't evaluate to `True`, and it doesn't.

> What I am suggesting is that if any of the sub-patterns fail then the whole pattern should fail; if none fail but some diverge then the whole pattern should diverge; and if all succeed then the whole pattern should succeed.

How could this be implemented? To find whether the first sub-pattern fails, you need to evaluate that argument; and if it diverges, the evaluation won't finish and the entire pattern match diverges by definition. You could try to evaluate all the patterns "in parallel", but this would greatly complicate the language: the current definition converts multiple equations into one which does `case` on the first argument, then on the second one, etc., so it doesn't introduce any new concepts; yours would have to.

I wouldn't quite say "`undefined` is supposed to represent a non-terminating calculation", but you aren't supposed to be able to distinguish them:

> [Errors in Haskell are semantically equivalent to ⊥ (“bottom”). Technically, they are indistinguishable from nontermination, so the language includes no mechanism for detecting or acting upon errors. However, implementations will probably try to provide useful information about errors. See Section 3.1.](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch1.html#x6-120001.3)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your first comment.

Your absolutely right about a non-terminating calculation, I hadn't thought of that.  I guess what I'm asking is that if `undefined` is supposed to represent a non-terminating calculation, but the compiler can tell that it never terminates, then why not have behaviour like I suggested?  If the result of a non-terminating calculation is irrelevant, then why make the pattern diverge anyway?

Comment: @RhubarbAndC: About the first comment: `null (undefined :: [a])` should not evaluate to `True`, since `undefined` isn't equal to the empty list. But it should also not evaluate to `False`, since `undefined` isn't equal to "any value being consed onto another list". There's only one way to get out of there: `null (undefined)` is… undefined. It's bottom (`_|_`). And if that's hidden somewhere in another evaluation, it's bottom all the way down.

Comment: For the first comment: again, think of a non-terminating calculation. Say, one that returns an empty list if it ever finds a solution to Fermat's theorem, so you can be pretty sure the compiler won't be able to tell if it terminates. Then calling `null` on it won't terminate either, so it's also undefined.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Don't tell that [the C++ programmers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNNnPrMHsAA&feature=youtu.be&t=480) :).

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I knew that `null undefined` is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

You are starting from a false premise.

> For instance: `undefined :: [Int]` is a list, so it must be constructed with either `[]` or `(:)`, but it doesn't know which one!

No, it is constructed with neither. `undefined :: [Int]` is a list in the sense of being a value of type `[a]` for some `a`. It is not a list in the sense of being constructed with either `[]` or `(:)`. This would be circular reasoning: "It is a list because it is constructed with `[]` or `(:)`. It is constructed with `[]` or `(:)` because it is a list."

> (By the way - if you disagree with my suggestion that `undefined` is built with a constructor, then surely `null (undefined :: [a])` should evaluate to `False`? After all undefined isn't equivalent to `[]`!)

By your logic, `let loop = loop in null loop` must also give `False` because `loop` isn't equivalent to `[]`, as must all other forms of non-termination. This would make `null` a solution to the Halting Problem*!

The mistake you have made is that `null` does not actually ask if the value is constructed with `[]` *or not*. It asks whether the value is constructed with `[]`, constructed with `(:)`, *or none of the above*. Since `undefined` is constructed with neither `[]` nor `(:)`, `null undefined` is neither `True` nor `False`. This is because Haskell's boolean logic is, in fact, a three-value system: `Bool` is inhabited by `True`, `False`, and bottom. It is entirely possible for a predicate to have an answer which is neither `True` nor `False`. Indeed, because Haskell is not a total language, it *must* be possible.

Here's another counterexample:

```
data Void
```

is a type with no constructors. If `undefined` must be constructed then it could not inhabit `Void` because `Void` has no constructors. But it *does* inhabit `Void`. GHC will happily accept `undefined :: Void`.

Since it is not true that `undefined` must be constructed, I won't address the rest of the arguments based on this premise.

Now, let's talk about why the given definition of `undefined` might be so. I will argue that `undefined` is a user-friendly alternative to nontermination for representing bottom.

Since Haskell is a non-total language with general recursion, one can always define:

```
undefined :: a
undefined = undefined
```

This `undefined` is a bottom value, an inhabitant of every type. However, it is not a particularly user-friendly bottom value because any scrutinization will cause a program to hang indefinitely. The `undefined` in the Prelude is a user-friendly alternative: scrutinization does not cause a program to hang but rather terminates the program immediately. However, in all other respects, `Prelude.undefined` must act like a bottom value if it is to be of use.

Consider the alternative, where `Prelude.undefined` was somehow observably different under evaluation from a "true" bottom value. This would mean that we have *two* extra inhabitants of every type: the "true" bottom value and an extra non-bottom value with subtly different semantics. This would not be useful, for what I hope are obvious reasons.

Thus, in order for `Prelude.undefined` to be useful, it must have equivalent behavior under evaluation to `undefined = undefined`. The fact that the behavior is not *identical* is a matter of convenience, but we can and should treat the result of its evaluation as *equivalent*. Consider the error that it throws to mean "GHC managed to detect this nonterminating program for you. You are welcome, but you might not be so lucky next time." In fact, by this logic you should also consider any values built using `error` to be similarly equivalent bottom values. It is the only useful, consistent interpretation.

---

* Or rather, `null` and a `notNull` that similarly checks for `(:)` and gives `False` for bottoms would form a solution to the halting problem: `halts x = null x || notNull x`.

Comment: So undefined doesn't mean "the programmer gave no definition" - it always represents an infinite loop.  The fact that it is used to plug gaps in incomplete definitions is just for convenience, and it really symbolises an infinite loop.  Surely this makes it a pretty bad choice of name?  Shouldn't it be called something a bit clearer, like neverEnd?

Comment: It turns out that a value which is an inhabitant of all types is useful for things besides being an infinite loop, especially one which terminates when scrutinized with a user-defined error message. `undefined` represents bottom, and it can be used for other things as well. The point is that if it did not have the semantics of bottom, it wouldn't be sensible.

Comment: Put another way, an infinite loop that magically terminated on scrutinization with an error message would be a very handy way of representing "the programmer gave no definition" in Haskell, since it can be used as a stand-in for a value of any type. That is exactly what `undefined` is, and hopefully explains why it is used in that way.

Comment: The *denotational* semantics here are less specific than the *operational* semantics based on imprecise exceptions. I suspect a denotational semantics for those would be too complicated to be useful.

Comment: @dfeuer Good point! I suppose I meant "semantics" in whatever way the report uses the term when it says that their semantics must be the same. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [The 2010 Haskell Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf), specifically, section 3.1 on Errors.

**Short answer:** Your example fails because of WHNF -> NF evaluation, which has to do with Haskell's laziness, which makes it possible that some values will never be used or "looked at"; if Haskell's laziness rules allow `undefined` to be skipped over, you won't get a crash and error code. Otherwise, you will. In that case, you did. Changing that behavior wouldn't involve changing `undefined` so much as it would involve changing Haskell's evaluation strategies.

**Observations:**

[] is just syntactic sugar for repeated application of (:) + a Nil, so it's not true that "it can be constructed with either", or it is true, but misleading, because they are actually the same thing.

The way you've phrased `undefined` make it seem as if it's a sensible value for cases where types (or pattern matches) aren't fully determinable, however, as far as I understand it, this is not the purpose of `undefined`. Rather, given that it has a type of `undefined :: t`, it allows you to place it inside of a function and have that function typecheck in most scenarios.

Let me phrase that another way: `undefined` *ought* to be used to leave a function in some real sense of the word, undefined, while allowing you to compile because `undefined`'s type will make it typecheck (otherwise you'd have to remove that function from scope). `undefined`, I do not believe, has any other purpose (and ideally, you should use `error` for this instead). If you call a function with `undefined` in it, *and* Haskell ever evaluates `undefined` (I think this would be taking it from a WHNF representation to NF), then you'll get a crash + error message.

The fact that people use `undefined` for other reasons like examining laziness properties of Haskell does not to me mean that `undefined` itself is supposed to have any behavior or properties other than throwing an error every time the compiler sees it. The fact that it does that is why it's a useful function for looking at those properties of Haskell. The key observation is that this shows how Haskell evaluates anything, not just `undefined`.

Comment: Meh, I've deleted my comment, but it still stands, you just moved the paragraph. It's not due to WHNF -> NF. After all `(Foo _ _)` is still not NF. And the second example fails due to left-to-right evaluation order in pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Complementary to all the other answers, there is a way to catch an exception. The downside is that you will have to perform your operation in the IO monad. I will explain. The things to look at are [`evaluate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate), [`try`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:try) and [`ErrorCall`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:ErrorCall). It works like this:

```
import Control.Exception

test :: a -> IO (Either ErrorCall a)
test val = try (evaluate val)

main = do
    result <- test (undefined :: String)
    print result
```

This will print

```
Left Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
 error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
 undefined, called at main.hs:7:21 in main:Main
```

While using anything other than `undefined` will the string, e.g.

```
Right "foo"
```